# Rendering custom item columns with sorting

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

Can anyone help me resolve the typing issues below for a FluentUI details list?

I have the following code to display a list of items using Fluent UI details list. I need to add the functionality to sort items in each column in ascending order
like this:

```
const buildColumns = (): IColumn[] => {
  const columns: IColumn[] = [];
  columns.push({
    key: "name",
    name: "Name",
    fieldName: "name",
    minWidth: 75,
    maxWidth: 75,
    isResizable: false,
    onColumnClick: _onColumnClick
  });
  columns.push({
    key: "age",
    name: "Age",
    fieldName: "age",
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 200,
    isResizable: false,
    onColumnClick: _onColumnClick
  });
  return columns;
}

function _copyAndSort<T>(items: T[], columnKey: string, isSortedDescending?: boolean): T[] {
    const key = columnKey as keyof T;
    return items.slice(0).sort((a: T, b: T) => ((isSortedDescending ? a[key] < b[key] : a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : -1));
}

const _onColumnClick = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, column: IColumn): void => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<[]>();
  const [names, setNames] = useState<[]>();
  const newColumns: IColumn[] = columns.slice(); // error: columns' is possibly 'undefined'.
  const currColumn: IColumn = newColumns.filter(currCol => column.key === currCol.key)[0];
  newColumns.forEach((newCol: IColumn) => {
    if (newCol === currColumn) {
    currColumn.isSorted = true;
    currColumn.isSortedDescending = !currColumn.isSortedDescending;
    } else {
    newCol.isSorted = false;
    newCol.isSortedDescending = true;
    }
  });
  const newItems = _copyAndSort(names, currColumn.fieldName!, currColumn.isSortedDescending); // error: Argument of type '[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
  setColumns(newColumns); // error: Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[] | undefined>'.
  Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
    Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.
  setNames(newItems); // error: Argument of type 'IColumn[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[] | undefined>'.
  Type 'IColumn[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
    Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.
}

export const NamesListBase: React.FunctionComponent<INamesListProps> = (
  props: INamesListProps
) => {

  var columns = buildColumns();
  const names = useSelector(selectAllNames)

  return (
    <div>
          <DetailsList
            items={names}
            columns={columns}
        />
      </div>
  ); 
}
```

Any pointers on how to fix these typing errors in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things that you can do to get this working. Here's a functional code sandbox to review: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-morning-8hqowd?file=/src/App.tsx

In short:

- Create state variables for the sorting field and direction
- In your `onColumnHeaderClick`, update the sorting state to be whatever column was clicked. If it's the same column twice, you could reverse the direction which is a nice UX.
- Create the list of columns and reference the state variables to decide if a certain column is currently sorted
- Sort the array of items using the new state variables
- Pass the sorted array into the DetailsList

The key is that sorting is *state* and, your list of items and columns need to be derived from that state in order for the interaction to work.

Hope that helps!

```js
export default function App() {
  const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [isSortedDescending, setIsSortedDescending] = useState(false);

  const items = [
    { age: 30, name: "Bob" },
    { age: 31, name: "Alice" }
  ];

  const columns: IColumn[] = [
    {
      key: "name",
      fieldName: "name",
      name: "Name",
      minWidth: 100,
      isSorted: sortKey === "name",
      isSortedDescending
    },
    {
      key: "age",
      fieldName: "age",
      name: "Age",
      minWidth: 100,
      isSorted: sortKey === "age",
      isSortedDescending
    }
  ];

  const sortedItems = [...items].sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortKey === "age") {
      return isSortedDescending ? b.age - a.age : a.age - b.age;
    }
    if (sortKey === "name") {
      return isSortedDescending
        ? b.name.localeCompare(a.name)
        : a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }
    return 0;
  });

  function onColumnHeaderClick(
    event?: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    column?: IColumn
  ) {
    if (column) {
      setIsSortedDescending(!!column.isSorted && !column.isSortedDescending);
      setSortKey(column.key);
    }
  }

  return (
    <DetailsList
      onColumnHeaderClick={onColumnHeaderClick}
      columns={columns}
      items={sortedItems}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what sortedItems does - what does it mean when it returns 0?

Comment: @user989988 sortedItems is just an array of items in sorted order. The return 0 part is for the comparator function that I pass to `Array.sort`. Here's what a compator is from the MDN docs: "A function that defines the sort order. The return value should be a number whose positivity indicates the relative order of the two elements."

In other words, if the comparator returns 0, that means that `a` and `b` don't have an order relative to each other (which is the case when a user hasn't clicked a column in table yet and there's no sorting).